# Concatenate and Justify in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have the data below:

[image]

I would like to locate the maximum length of the string of texts in the first column, and from there count the number of spaces to position the second concatenated item to align. My attempt to concatenate has the below formula

=A1&REPT(" ",40-LEN(A1))&TEXT(B1,"0.00%")

and only got this so far as the format:

[image]

I want to be able to achieve this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to use a [Monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Comment: Why not just remove the border between the cells so it looks like one cell and align the numbers left?

Comment: I have special reasons for concatenating the columns. I discovered that the spaces from concatenated columns can be retained if you post the data on Skype, compared to manually adding spaces in Excel, which does not.

Comment: Are you required to have merged cells? Or the data in one cell? You could put the words in one column, and their numbers next to it, then just format (via coloring/borders) the cells to look as one?

Comment: Then you will need to use a monospaced font.

Comment: Another idea is to get the `len()` of just your text. Then find out the max characters that will fit in your cell. Then you can just add spaces with `totalCharactersAllowed - Len([text[)`, if that makes sense?

Comment: @BruceWayne one cell to concatenate 5 columns. This is actually for posting on Skype. Having a hard time 'formatting' the columns for columns to correctly display

Comment: @kenkenhimself "for posting on Skype" - what's your ultimate goal with the concatenating? To easily copy into Skypes text field? We may have a little bit of an X/Y Problem.

Comment: @BruceWayne Easily copy into Skype with the format for each column. I meantioned this to Scott: "I have special reasons for concatenating the columns. I discovered that the spaces from concatenated columns can be retained if you post the data on Skype, compared to manually adding spaces in Excel, which does not."

Comment: If you want a consisten outcome, you should definitely look at using a mono-spaced font like Scott mentioned twice already.

Comment: Hi @RobinMackenzie, my bad for not acknowledging Scott's suggestion, which I've already taken into consideration. My problem now is to retain the format and column spacing when pasting the data to Skype. Thanks!

Comment: Great, thanks for this, @ScottCraner!